# Sending email with file attachment with file path

Tags: php, html

I have image path, and able to display image path url in the mail.

But need to display image instead, path.

Getting output like this.

[image]

Here is my code..

```
$image = "Image Path";
$to      = "abc@xyz.com";
$subject = "Subject";
$message = $description."<br /><img src=".$image." />";
$header = "From: bhavanram93@gmail.com \r\n";
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if( $retval == true )
{
echo "Successfull!!"
}
```

Comment: See [<img>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: @showdev, I wanna display image instead image path.

Comment: What goes wrong that prevents you from doing that?

Comment: See the output i'm getting..

Comment: How is `$image` defined? `echo $image;`

Comment: When i tried echo $image, getting 500 internal server error.